# Плавное закрытие details через css

Tags: html, css, анимация

Есть такой вопрос. Есть спойлер details. я реализовал в нём плавное раскрытие. По-идее, он должен так же плавно закрываться, но нет. В чем может быть проблема?
[ссылка на CodePen](https://codepen.io/Sfairath/pen/QWaypwM) и код прилагаются. **JS не предлагать.**

```css
.spoiler {
  border-top: 1px solid #cacaca;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cacaca;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spoiler__cross {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spoiler__header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer
}

.spoiler-content {
  width: 43%;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.spoiler:hover,
.spoiler:focus {
  border-color: #ff9900;
}

.spoiler:hover>.spoiler__header,
.spoiler:focus>.spoiler__header {
  color: #ff9900;
}

.spoiler[open] {
  border-color: #cacaca;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.spoiler[open]>.spoiler__header {
  color: inherit;
}

.spoiler[open] .spoiler__cross {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<details class="spoiler faq__spoiler">
  <summary class="spoiler__header">
    Из чего формируется конечная стоимость проекта?
    <svg class="spoiler__cross" width="50" height="50" viewbox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <ellipse cx="25" cy="25" rx="25" ry="25" fill="#ECECEC"/>
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M25.0571 24.0571L25.0571 9L25.9429 9L25.9429 24.0571L33.8835 24.0571L41 24.0571L41 24.9429L25.9429 24.9429L25.9429 40L25.0571 40L25.0571 24.9429L10 24.9429L10 24.0571L25.0571 24.0571Z" fill="#666666"/>
    </svg>
  </summary>
  <div class="spoiler-content">
    <p class="spoiler-content__text">
      Являясь всего лишь частью общей картины, непосредственные участники технического прогресса призывают нас к новым свершениям, которые, в свою очередь, должны быть своевременно верифицированы. Но высококачественный прототип будущего проекта является качественно
      новой ступенью первоочередных требований. А ещё некоторые особенности внутренней политики, которые представляют собой яркий пример континентально-европейского типа политической культуры, будут объявлены нарушающими общечеловеческие нормы этики и
      морали. И нет сомнений, что явные признаки победы институционализации призывают нас к новым свершениям, которые, в свою очередь, должны быть указаны как претенденты на роль ключевых факторов.
    </p>
    <p class="spoiler-content__text">
      Приятно, граждане, наблюдать, как некоторые особенности внутренней политики могут быть призваны к ответу. Явные признаки победы институционализации набирают популярность среди определенных слоев населения, а значит, должны быть объединены в целые кластеры
      себе подобных. Банальные, но неопровержимые выводы, а также многие известные личности призывают нас к новым свершениям, которые, в свою очередь, должны быть представлены в исключительно положительном свете.
    </p>
  </div>
</details>
```

Comment: Если в `.spoiler` открытый и закрытый добавить `height` с конкретным значением и сделать `transition: all`, то будет плавно сворачиваться, но встанет проблема с размерами

Comment: В таком случае при закрытии ```.spoiler``` содержимое пропадёт сразу, а анимация сработает корректно, да.